# Android - Use admin policy to configure app preferences remotely on multiple devices

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am working on some corporate app for Android which will be installed on all the company owned devices.

We need the company admins to be able to configure some [preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference) in the app. preferrably remotely using policy or any other method without need to hardcode the preferences changes in the code and redeploy it on all devices all over again.

Do android API has such feature?

I've looked into the [`Device administration`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin) (which should be [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation) soon) but it doesn't seems to be what I am searching for.

I want to be able to remotly setup keys in the [sharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) just like a [PreferenceActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity) would do.

We could also build some private REST server to call it from the app in order to retrieve the preferences we want and programmatically setup them.. but I'll be happy to find simpler out-of-box feature to do that without the need to maintain a server.

Any Idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Do android API has such feature?" -- no.

Comment: As commonsWare mentioned, there is not out-of-the-box solution to what you are looking for. Besides, you might also be looking at creating some sortof web admin console to create/manage different policies inaddition to some sortof database to store the policies. There are some applications that offer mobile device management functionality as to what you are looking for: To name a few: 1. [Mobile Iron](http://mobileiron.com). 2. [AirWatch](http://airwatch.com). 3. [WaZa MDM](https://wazamdm.com).